# TYPO3 extbase Column value NULL

Tags: typo3, extbase

TYPO3 10.4.16

I have created a table with a column `year int(11) DEFAULT NULL` . But if I try to use the repository with `$track->setYear(null)`, I always get the error message `Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'year' at row 1`.

Does extbase not allow an empty value or do I have to change something?

**Edit:**

```
/**
 * year
 * 
 * @var int
 */
protected $year = null;




/**
 * Returns the year
 * 
 * @return int $year
 */
public function getYear()
{
    return $this->year;
}

/**
 * Sets the year
 * 
 * @param int $year
 * @return void
 */
public function setYear($year)
{
    $this->year = $year;
}
```

Comment: TYPO3 uses Doctrine, so you can search for clues in this direction, following i.e. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54921253/1066240) I would try to use 'NULL' (string, wrapped with single quotes, uppercase)

Comment: I tried it with the `'NULL'` string, but got the same error message. Maybe why it is specified as int.

Comment: Very fast workaround: set `0` for no values, later I'll check that thing

Comment: Just tested your case at 10.4.16 and there is no problem with null convention. Show us your `setYear()` method and also`$year` property with all annotations.

Comment: See info under edit

Comment: Your getter and setter expects / return INT .. 
you should  change "int" agains "int|null" 
and: i think the the Doctrines SQl statement in 10.4 is generated from Configuration ->TCA -> Model -> Columns -> config -> 
Maybe eval = 'int'